# Lock mouse pointer to first screen when using extended display and two screens

Tags: windows, gratis, mouse, multi-monitor

I am using two screens on my desktop computer.

It is extremely easy when I'm writing code or document on one and browsing on the other. However, problems occur when I play games.

Nearly all the games require mouse pointer to be at the edge of the screen to look/rotate the character or camera etc.

It becomes impossible with two screens since when I slide the mouse to the right, it passes to the other screen and hence I cannot use the camera efficientlty.
One way to solve this is to use only one screen while in game.

However, in some games, such as DoTA, LoL, Counter-Strike, Civilization etc. you wait either to be respawned or for your turn.
At that interval, I would like to do something else on the other screen.
Therefore, I do not want to switch back and forth between extended display and second-screen only.

As a result, I want to use a **free** software that runs on **Windows** and has the ability of locking the mouse pointer to a specific screen when I use a hotkey (for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>).

Could you recommend me one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Cursor Lock](http://www.snakebytestudios.com/projects/apps/cursor-lock/):

- free
- lets you define shortcuts to lock the cursor to the current screen/window
- also lets you choose it to auto-lock when a certain program is running
- runs on Windows

What you want to do (lock with a shortcut) is called `User Mode` in the program.

So, to set it up, go to `User Mode` > `Lock Region: screen` > `Shortcuts` and set your shortcuts:

[image]